# Working through the Untangled Template

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I'm very interested in using CLJS and Untangled to make a dynamic web app.  I have some very basic questions, though.  My first question is:  I see that like in other frameworks, there is a base `index.html` that has a `.js` file reference and the `<div id="app"></div>` is tied to the javascript file.

So in the Untangled Template project from github, I have my Figwheel server running and I wanted to do some tinkering on the dev-index side.

```
<body>
    <div class="container-fluid" id="app"><div>Now loading super sweet app</div></div>
    <script src="js/untangled_template.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
```

However, there's no file called `untangled_template.js` and I'm wondering what would be the bare minimum scaffolding for such a .js file.

Having used Clojure, but not really broken into Clojurescript yet, I'm curious how this .js file comes to be (since presumably it's first written in cljs)

Thanks many

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I've never used Untangled.*

[This line of the Untangled template's `project.clj`](https://github.com/untangled-web/untangled-template/blob/develop/project.clj#L47) is probably what you're looking for. Note how in the `:cljsbuild` section of this file, there are several builds listed - when you run `lein figwheel`, the `dev` profile is used, and whenever you make changes to your cljs code, Figwheel compiles your cljs (note the `:source-paths` part of this build map) and puts the generated JS in `resources/public/js/untangled_template.js`.

You say you're not seeing an `untangled_template.js` file - do you mean that you don't see a file with that name in the root directory of your Leiningen project, or do you mean that when you load your `index.html` in a Web browser it complains that it can't find `/js/untangled_template.js`?

Comment: Thank you.  That's right on.  I really like Untangled, I'm gonna try building up to that level of functionality from the Om.next quickstart... perhaps arriving at the same place =)